# prefer conversion operator over conversion constructor

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
public:
  A() : x_(0), y_(0) {}

  A(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}

  template<class T>
  A(const T &rhs) : x_(rhs.x_), y_(rhs.y_)
  {
  }

  int x_, y_;
};

class B
{
public:
  B() {}

  operator A() const { return A(c[0],c[1]); }
  int c[2];
};

void f()
{
  B b;
  (A)b; // << here the error appears, compiler tries to use 
        //         template<class T> A(const T &rhs)
}
```

Why compiler uses `A`'s constructor? How can I make it use `B`'s conversion operator to `A`?

I use MSVS2010 compiler. It gives me these errors:

```
main.cpp(9): error C2039: 'x_' : is not a member of 'B'
          main.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'B'
          main.cpp(28) : see reference to function template instantiation 'A::A<B>(const T &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=B
          ]
main.cpp(9): error C2039: 'y_' : is not a member of 'B'
          main.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'B'
```

**UPD**:
All right, implicit convert as Nawaz said really works. Let's make it more complicated, how make the following code work?

```
void f()
{
  std::vector<B> b_vector(4);
  std::vector<A> a_vector( b_vector.begin(), b_vector.end() );
}
```

**UPD**: `A` is the class in 3rd party lib which code I can't edit, so I can't remove `A`'s converting constructor.

**UPD**: the simplest solution I've found for the moment is to define specialization of converting constructor for `B`. It can be done outside of 3rd party lib:

```
template<> A::A( const B &rhs ) : x_(rhs.c[0]), y_(rhs.c[1]) {}
```

Answer (score 9):

The reason is **not** only because it thinks `(A)b` is same as `A(b)`. The standard says this about explicit type-conversion (5.4):

> The conversions performed by
>
> - a const_cast (5.2.11),
> - a static_cast (5.2.9),
> - a static_cast followed by a const_cast,
> - a reinterpret_cast (5.2.10), or
> - a reinterpret_cast followed by a const_cast,
>
> can be performed using the cast
>   notation of explicit type conversion.
>   The same semantic restrictions and
>   behaviors apply.

Essentially this means that even for explicit type-conversion of `(A)b` (i.e. if you used `((A)b);` to prevent from it being a variable declaration). it'd use the rules of `static_cast`. Now let's take a look at what the standard says about `static_cast` (5.2.9):

> An expression e can be explicitly
>   converted to a type T using a
>   static_cast of the form
>   static_cast(e) if the declaration
>   “T t(e);” is well-formed, for some
>   invented temporary variable t (8.5).
>   The effect of such an explicit
>   conversion is the same as performing
>   the declaration and initialization and
>   then using the temporary variable as
>   the result of the conversion. The
>   result is an lvalue if T is a
>   reference type (8.3.2), and an rvalue
>   otherwise. The expression e is used as
>   an lvalue if and only if the
>   initialization uses it as an lvalue.

If you do `static_cast<A>(b)`, it basically sees if `A(b)` is well-formed; and **it is**. Just because the actual instantiation of the template function copy-constructor fails, it doesn't make the actual declaration is ill-formed, hence it uses it and ultimately fails.

Comment: It's a very fine line here though, I think. Of course, a declaration `A t(b);` is not well-formed, otherwise it wouldn't yell at us. Perhaps one reason it's regarded as well-formed is because the description of the phases of translation at 2.2 puts the instantiation of templates *after* the translation of translation units (phase 7 vs phase 8). So it requires implementations to disregard the result of instantiation when determining how to translate a translation unit (which also happens for SFINAE: it cannot detect failure of instantiations - such things are hard errors).

Comment: +1, I almost asked a question that would have got a similar answer, but S5.2.9 clarified it.

Answer (score 5):

From 5.4/1 and 5.4/5 the C-cast picks the "best choice" C++ cast from a list. In this case, that's a `static_cast`.

Then from 5.2.9/2:

> An expression e can be explicitly
>   converted to a type T using a
>   static_cast of the form
>   static_cast(e) if the declaration
>   “T t(e);” is well formed, for some
>   invented temporary variable t (8.5).
>   The effect of such an explicit
>   conversion is the same as performing
>   the declaration and initialization and
>   then using the temporary variable as
>   the result of the conversion. The
>   result is an lvalue if T is a
>   reference type (8.3.2), and an rvalue
>   otherwise. The expression e is used as
>   an lvalue if and only if the
>   initialization uses it as an lvalue.

So it picks the constructor before even attempting any other option.

In this case you've defined two conversions to get to the same end result, but the language has specific rules dictating that it will always use the available constructor. You should probably leave the constructor and change the operator to an explicit `as`-type function instead.

EDIT for OP's edit:
I don't think you'll be able to use the vector `iter, iter` constructor. You'll need to start with an empty vector and either use a for loop with `push_back` or use `std::transform`.

Answer (score 3):

```
(A)b; // << here the error appears, compiler tries to use
```

This is *explicit*  casting to `A`. Hence the constructor of `A` gets invoked to convert `b` to `A`.

```
A a(1,2);
a = b ; //this will invoke user-defined conversion of B (implicit conversion)
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/K9IxT

Comment: Well, I noticed that =) This is the heart of the problem. Is there any way to make compiler use conversion operator of `B` and not conversion constructor of `A`.

Comment: Yep, implicit convert really works, but look at question UPD, please =)

Comment: @pure cuteness Remove the converting constructor or make the operator a named function that you explicitly call. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I can't remove converting constructor because `A` is the class in some 3rd party library which code I can't edit.

Comment: Or you may consider `boost::implicit_cast<A>(b)` (this relies on the constructor being a template, and the conversion function being not).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, given the choice between a well-formed constructor and a conversion operator, the compiler will always call the constructor. But you could call the conversion operator directly, if you wish:

```
A a = b.operator A();
```

Comment: @Cubbi: `given the choice between a well-formed constructor and a conversion operator, the compiler will always call the constructor` Not really. The compiler will call the constructor, if its *templated* constructor.

Comment: @Nawaz The constructor need not be a template at all. As long as the constructor can be legally matched to the "cast-from" type the constructor will always be preferred.

Comment: @Mark: No. The call will be ambiguous then.

Comment: @Nawaz why only? The choice between `A::A(const B &rhs)` and `B::operator A()()` would also be a call to the constructor, whether `A(b);` or `(A)b;` or `static_cast<A>(b)` is used.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm pretty sure that `5.3.9/2` says that about converting constructors regardless of what a particular implementation does.

Answer (score 1):

As for the second part of your question on how to make it working, I would use `std::transform` instead of modifying/adding something in the 3rd-party library namespace, unless only this library is well documented and it is intended that you should specialize this constructor:

```
a_vector.reserve( b_vector.size() );
std::transform( b_vector.begin(), b_vector.end(), 
  std::back_inserter( a_vector ), boost::bind( &B::operator A, _1 ) );
```

Answer (score -2):

The syntax `(A)b` is the same as `A(b)`, which is a construction. If you want a cast, then you must explicitly use `static_cast`, for example.

Comment: If I'm reading 5.4/1 and 5.4/5 correctly `(A)b` would actually be treated as a `static_cast`.

Comment: @Mark and @DeadMG: `static_cast<A>(b)` will call the constructor of `A`.

Comment: Nawaz is right; I added explanation of why it happens in my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz yes and that will generate compile errors as `x_` and `y_` are not members of `B` there may be some missing inheritance in the example code.

Comment: @AJG85: Yes. But that is a different issue. We're not discussing it here.